# Circular dependency between services

Tags: angularjs

I have the following case:

I have the following services:

```
angular.module('countries.services', [
  'language.services'
])

.service('CountriesService', ['LanguageService', '$http', function(LanguageService, $http) {

  this.fetchCountries = function() {
    $http.get('myaddress.com/' + LanguageService.currentLanguage).then(function() {
     //do something
    });
  };
}]);
```

AND

```
angular.module('language.services', [
  'countries.services'
])

.service('LanguageService', ['CountriesService', function(CountriesService) {
  this.currentLanguage = null;
  this.setLanguage = function(l) {
    currentLanguage  = l;
    CountriesService.fetchCountries();
  };
}]);
```

The logic behind this is that each time a language is being selected, I want to fetch countries list in the language that is selected. I also want whenever I call CountriesService.fetchCountries(), the currently selected language to be used as a language that the countries are translated in.

Seems to me that is pretty normal case. Is there a way that I can solve this issue in Angular?

Comment: You need another way for the services to communicate. You could try using events. Otherwise you will need to refactor to break the circular dep (have one service depend on the other, AND have it be the call-through interface to the service it depends on).

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the current language as a parameter to your `fetchCountries` method.

`CountriesService.fetchCountries(this.currentLanguage);`

AND

```
this.fetchCountries = function(language) {
    $http.get('myaddress.com/' + language).then(function() {
     //do something
    });
};
```

Or, you could use the $rootScope to store the current language. Something like this :

```
angular.module('language.services', [
'countries.services'
])

.service('LanguageService', ['$rootScope', 'CountriesService', function($rootScope, CountriesService) {
  this.currentLanguage = null;
  $rootScope = this.currentLanguage;

  this.setLanguage = function(l) {
    currentLanguage  = l;
    CountriesService.fetchCountries();
    $rootScope = this.currentLanguage;
  };
}]);
```

AND

```
angular.module('countries.services', [])

.service('CountryService', ['$rootScope', '$http', function($rootScope, $http) {

  this.fetchCountries = function() {
    $http.get('myaddress.com/' + $rootScope.currentLanguage).then(function() {
     //do something
    });
  };
}]);
```